# empty array returned with user_photos permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, deprecated

I was using the `user_photo_video_tags` permission, but after it was [announced that it would be deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/544/), I switched the permission to `user_photos`.

Without `user_photo_video_tags` and with only `user_photos`, I get the following response when making an authenticated call to 'me/photos':

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

but with `user_photo_video_tags` I get the correct response with tagged photos and uploaded photos.

Isn't `user_photos` + `user_videos` supposed to be equivalent to `user_photo_video_tags`? Why am I getting different results?

*(there are a few similar questions out there, but I do not believe they are the same use case)*

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you're seeing here. I can try it using the Graph API Explorer with user_photos, and I get the expected results: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos

Comment: Right, but you also most likely have "user_photo_video_tags" ticked off by default (which you cannot remove in the explorer for some reason)